# WSO2 APIM 3.2 - AccessToken Cache doesn't work when using JWT Access Token

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 AM 3.2 in a distributed environment (Publisher, DevPortal, KM , Gateway & Traffic Manager on separate VMs).

I did a Migration from a 2.6 platform , hence all my migrated applications use Opaque AccessToken & not JWT ones (which is the new standard).

I noticed the following behavior :

- When I invoque the /Token API with an Application that has an Opaque Tokens : The Gateway Cache works perfectly (the gateway invoques /token on the key manager for the first call only & caches it during 15mn).
- But when I invoque the /Token API with an Application that has an JWT Tokens, the Token is never cached , not in the Gateway side Nor the Key Manager side , & it provokes very big problems of performance since the KM always generates & sign a new JWT AccessToken for every call.

Is it a bug in the product or have I missed something ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you configured this "[apim.cache.jwt_claim]" in APIM 3.2.0? https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-gateway/passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt/#expiry-time-of-the-jwt

Comment: It had an issue[1], but it has been fixed now.[1]. https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/11260